# forEach nested to match

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, foreach

Here i made a code.

`let StaffParsed = JSON.parse(params.StaffJson);
console.log(StaffParsed)`

Here is the result below fo console log.

```
Object
cellPhoneNo: "1234567890"
createdBy: "1"
createdDate: "2020-05-09T17:26:31.743"
email: "ravi@email.com"
fax: "1234567890"
firstName: "Ravi"
id: 1004
lastName: "Nikam"
phoneNo: "1234567890"
profilePic: ""
sendEmail: false
sendPhone: false
status: "3"
title: "Mr."
type: "2"
updatedBy: "1"
updatedDate: null
username: "ravi109"
__proto__: Object
```

I have this model created here is the code below.

```
public StaffModel : Staff = new Staff();
console.log(this.StaffModel);
```

Its console log result is below.

```
Staff
CellPhoneNo: 0
CnfPassword: ""
CreatedBy: ""
CreatedDate: null
Email: ""
Fax: 0
FirstName: ""
FormStaffGroup: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, pristine: true, touched: false, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
Id: null
LastName: ""
Password: ""
PhoneNo: 0
ProfilePic: ""
SendEmail: false
SendPhone: false
Status: "0"
Title: ""
Type: "0"
UpdatedBy: ""
UpdatedDate: null
UserName: ""
__proto__: Object
enter code here
```

**Now i want to match with the above first object list with the second list and update the second list model**, so far i have tried this code.

```
Object.keys(StaffParsed).forEach(function(keyParsed) {        
    Object.keys(this.StaffModel).forEach((keyModel: string) => {          
      if(keyParsed == keyModel){
        keyParsed = this.StaffModel[keyModel];
      }
    });
  });
```

But in return, it shows error like this [image: error].

Comment: Please click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with an ACTUAL object, not a console.log of an object

Comment: Convert your first function to arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this part:

```
... .forEach(function(keyParsed) {        
Object.keys(this.StaffModel)
```

`this` does not propagate into functions like that. As such, the `this` inside the function has a different value from the `this` in the outside function.

If you want the function to inherit the `this` of the outside scope, use an arrow function instead. (`(keyParsed) => {` instead of `function(keyParsed) {`)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` in `this.StaffModel[keyModel]` may refer to the function not global.

Try this:

```
let that = this;
Object.keys(StaffParsed).forEach(function (keyParsed) {
    Object.keys(that.StaffModel).forEach((keyModel: string) => {
        if (keyParsed == keyModel) {
            keyParsed = that.StaffModel[keyModel];
        }
    });
});
```